# Why don't all of my uploaded video clips appear in the YouTube online video editor?

Tags: youtube

I've got several video clips uploaded to YouTube that I'd like to use the video editor to splice together. Only a subset of my uploaded clips are available in the clips panel in the editor. Any idea how to get the other ones into the editor?

Comment: There is a thread about this on the Youtube help forum at:  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=7261976b8145f38b&hl=en

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:

The video editor is no longer available to use on YouTube, making both question and answer irrelevant. Original answer follows*

---

There are several reasons why videos may not show up:

- The video is too long (limit currently is at 1 hour, YouTube is working on extending that though)
- The video contains copyrighted content by a third party
- The video has not finished processing yet
- The video has been deleted